# Usage of "when" followed by verb+ing

Tags: grammaticality, present-participles

Is it okay to use "when" immediately followed by a verb ending with *-ing*?

For example:

> - When climbing the hill,...
> - When writing a book,...

Comment: These are fine, and are obvious ellipted forms of 'When / while _one is / we were / you will be_ climbing the hill' etc as context demands. Interestingly, it is harder to see where 'After / since climbing the hill' come from, and why *'During climbing the hill' / *'As climbing the hill' aren't used in the same way.

Comment: _During_ and _as_ both mean simply _climbing the hill_, without introduction, as a free and therefore dangleable participial phrase. I surmise that if [Whiz deletion or a similar rule](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/93947/15299) is operating to reduce syllables, adding _during_ or _as_ at the beginning is counterindicated.

Answer (score 2):

The construction **when + *-ing* form + complement** is acceptable, and very common in written English. It is not often encountered in spoken English, however, which generally prefers a finite clause:

- When climbing the hill they discovered an ancient footpath.
- When they were climbing the hill they discovered an ancient footpath.

Be careful in using this construction that you do not create a *dangling* participle. The implied subject of the verb must be the same as the clause to which the *when*-clause is subordinated.

> <sup>ok</sup> When climbing the hill they discovered an ancient footpath. ...
>   <sup>∗</sup>  When climbing the hill, John stayed behind to explore the ruined hut.

---

<sup>∗</sup>  *marks an utterance as unacceptable.*

Answer (score -2):

Grammatically ***when*** here means ***while***, and it functions as a conjunction.

conjunction = a word that is  used to connect parts of sentences , phrases or

clauses like" but" , " and " or" while " .

Comment: Spaces **never** get inserted after an open-quote, and spaces come **after**, a comma, not before. Same with terminal punctuation – there is **no** blank space between the end of the sentence and the period. Also, while you're correct about the meaning of the word _when_ in this context, I think you should elaborate more on what you mean by them being conjunctions.